# How to add an input and remove it if existed with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form and I want to add new input in that and if this input existed remove that or prevent from being added.
In my code just added one input and when I try to add another different input first input cleans
Body :

```
<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">name<br />
            <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">add</a>
            <div id="container"/>
```

footer:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function addFields(){

        var name = document.getElementById("member").value;

        var container = document.getElementById("container");

        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
            container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        }
        for (i=0;i<1;i++){

            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name+ (i+1)));

            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = name;
            container.appendChild(input);
            // Append a line break
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Put the names in an array then test `if(array.indexOf(newName) !== -1)`. Be careful on those global vars too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelector('#member')` to check if the input exists or not.

```js
function addFields() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  if (!container.querySelector('#member')) {
    container.innerHTML = `<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">name`;
    console.log('input added');
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">add</a>
<div id="container">

</div>
```